# What is the maximum Cho'Gath's ultimate damage

Tags: league-of-legends

I was looking at my wife game, when she played as Annie in EUW. In enemy team there was a Cho'Gath who did **2753** true damage using his ultimate.

That is far beyond what i thought was possible. It happened around 42 - 47 min.

[image]

At 47:59 Cho'Gath's had following items:

- Mercury's Treads with Homegauards
- Spirit Visage
- Rod of Ages
- Banshee's Veil
- Luden's Echo
- Rabadon's Deathcap

With total of 539 ap

[image]

Other enemy team members who could have modified him are:

- Amumu
- Gangplank
- Twitch
- Blitzcrank

his runes
[image]

and masteries
[image]

can anyone explain this (even if it is a bug)?

Comment: Are you talking about death recap? Because that is notoriously buggy; many times it shows things that don't make any sense.

Comment: As a software engineer I can find sense where others see little. I could write a logger that logs all incoming damage and actully verify this if i had recorded the full game.

Comment: This won't account for all of it, but you can have negative resistances. I think Silentvenom7 hit the nail on the head about death recap. It's not very accurate, and sometimes wildly inaccurate.

Comment: @nukeforum not to true damage

Comment: @margus can you state if you saw this number in the death recap or if it was a damage number that appeared when cho gath used feast?

Comment: @Aequitas I'm pretty embarrassed that I even mentioned it. You're right, of course.

Comment: @Aequitas recap

Comment: That the death recap is buggy is well-known. This has always been like that and seems to be not getting fixed in the future...

Answer (score 2):

539 AP, 650+70% AP damage means that he dealt 1027 points of true damage.

That's a lot, but it's nothing like 2753 so there are two possibilities:

1. You misread the death damage display somehow (there's no way to check since you haven't got a screenshot of it)
2. Luden's Echo somehow confused things. It could have caused a magic damage proc as well as the true damage. That magic damage hitting multiple targets.
3. There are no other options really since true damage is never modified by anything.

I've never tested it but it's plausible that that combined with the massive amounts of AoE magic damage Cho does caused a bug in the death display.

It seems very unlikely that it actually dealt that much damage (and I've played Cho a lot and it's never happened to me). That sort of bug would be extremely serious and get fixed fast so it's far more likely to be a display issue.

It might be worth submitting this as a bug report to Riot though so they can investigate.

Comment: Luden's doesn't proc with Cho's R

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I've not tested it but I don't see why it wouldn't? Luden's Echo applies to all ability damage. It's not only on dealing magic damage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug.

Cho'Gath would need over 3k AP in order to hit that high with his ult.

The death recap often displays incorrect or misleading information. There have been cases where 500 damage was attributed to *Revive*.

It's possible that the 2753 damage that you see attributed to his ult was actually partially from other sources and not just the ult.

Possibly damage sources not listed in the death recap gets their damage attributed to a different source. It's impossible to tell but this is a bug or at least a misleading aspect of the death recap.

With only 600 AP Cho'Gath could not have done this much damage, even if his ult was used twice and somehow both of them displayed in the death recap, it would still not reach the shown damage.

If you have a replay, look for the moment where he ults and there will be a number that appears indicating how much damage was done by the ult. This number is much more certain to be accurate.